# Partial document update in SOLR 6.5.1

Tags: solr, nutch, solr6

I have ID(unique key) and URL fields in my indexed document. They have same values. **And I am able to update the URL field(changing the DNS)** as following:

**{"*id*":"ABC.com/content/dam/images/infographics/Infographic_Final.pdf","*url*":{"set":"XYZ.com/content/dam/images/infographics/Infographic_Final.pdf"}}**

what i am trying to achieve is i have 1000 documents having field **ID** starting with *ABC.com*. It should update **URL** field with *XYZ.com* and the rest of the URL-path must remain the same. can i achieve this? i dont want to  update URL repeatedly for 1000 times.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking for a 'bulk update' like SQL's 'UPDATE table WHERE...' that is not possible in Solr. You have to submit each doc (mind you, you can submit many docs in one request, but all doc's info must be in there).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it using Java program. I used Solr-query to find all **ID** starting with *ABC.com*. I got **URL** corresponding to that **ID** and **replaced ABC.com with XYZ.com** and kept the rest of the path same. Used **set command** and updated all the **URLs(only URL field)** using while loop.

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8090/solr/collectionName";
    SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
    SolrQuery query=new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery("id:*ABC*");
    query.setRows(2147483647);
    QueryRequest req = new QueryRequest(query);
    QueryResponse response = req.process(solrClient);   
    SolrDocumentList docList=response.getResults();
    Iterator <SolrDocument> itr=docList.iterator();


    String IdValue="";
     Map<String, String> cmd1;
     Map<String, String> cmd2;
     UpdateRequest ureq=new UpdateRequest();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        JSONObject resultItems = new JSONObject();
        SolrDocument doc= itr.next();
        IdValue=(String)doc.getFieldValue("id");

        SolrInputDocument newdoc = new SolrInputDocument();

        cmd1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String URL=IdValue.replace("www.ABC.com", "www.XYZ.com");
        cmd1.put("set", URL);
        newdoc.addField("id", IdValue);
        newdoc.addField("url", cmd1);
        ureq.add(newdoc);

        cmd1=null;
        cmd2=null;
        }

    NamedList res = solrClient.request(ureq);
    System.out.println(" response "+res);

    solrClient.commit();
    solrClient.close();
```